# cannot center complex content with max-width set

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with centering content that has max-width element set. The spacing on the left and right is not the same. [This is a pen to my project](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGqJzW). The problem appears to originate form
`side-post, span_1_of_3`, because of variable margin on the right.

I tried

```
 .inner {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

 .outer2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

I am a little confused about what could be the solution to this probelm. Any ideas how to solve it?

This image shows the cenetering problem I am facing:

[image]

Comment: What is the element with `max-width` applied to it that is not centering?

Comment: .container element

Comment: Hm, actually the centering on a div is working. It is solely a problem of side-post, span_1_of_1. This is more complex than I originally thought.

Comment: what content exactly you want to center? can you be more clear added an answer ...is that what you are looking for

Comment: The entire outer2. Which is centered, but it appears it isnt, because some margins issues going on with side-post

Comment: Let us know what helped you...consider accepting one of the answers

Comment: `span_1_of_1` does not exist in your code.

Comment: span_1_of_3. silly me

Answer (score 1):

Remove width: 15em; from .side-post and spacing will be equal

Comment: It does at the pen you shared. If it doesn't work on your site or locally, then your code is different than the code at pen or your css is cached.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. i think codepen doesnt cache. Perhaps we misunderstood each other. I was trying to have the same spacing on the far left (and edge of screen) and far right(and enge of right screen) of the main content. On big screens, it appears so, but on smaller it is evident that something is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:flex on .outer2 and justify-content:center and align-items:center,it should center all your content

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Base Styles */

body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 color: #222;
 background: red;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

img{
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.outer2{
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  display: flex;

}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}



/* Grid */

.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


.span_2_of_3 {
 width: 67.1%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
 width: 31.2%;
}


/* Header & Navigation */





/* Blog Posts */

.container{
 max-width: 1420px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
}



.side-post{
 background: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto 1.5em auto;
 width: 15em;
 padding: 20px;
}



.side-content{
 font-size: .9em;
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}



.date{
 
 text-decoration-color: currentColor;
}



/* Button */

.button{
 display: block;
 padding: 15px 20px;
 margin-top: .8em;
 background: #009ACD;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 transition: all .4s ease-in;
}

.button:hover{
 background: #005c7b;
}

/*Media Queries*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.span_2_of_3 {
 width: 75.1%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
 width: 17.2%;
}
}

/* @900px*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 56.25em) {
 .col{ margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;}
 .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3{ width: 100%; }
 .side-post{ width: 42%;
      float: left;
      margin: -2% 0 1% 1.6%;}
}

/* @685px*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 42.813em) {
 .side-post{ width: auto;
    padding: 15px;
       margin: -2% auto 8% auto; }
 .date{ font-size: .9em; }  
}

/* @480px */

/* @380px*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 23.75em) {
 .side-content{ font-size: .8em; }
 .button{ padding: 10px 15px; }
}




/*CONTENT OF LEFT SIDE*/
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*PEN STYLES*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Roboto:400,700);

.blog-card {
 transition: height 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 margin: 0 auto 1.6%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.45em;
 height:460px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


.blog-card:hover .details {
 left: 0;
}

.blog-card:hover.alt .details {
 right: 0;
}

.blog-card.alt .details {
 right: -100%;
 left: inherit;
}

.blog-card .photo {
 height: 200px;
 position: relative;
}

.blog-card .photo.photo1 {
 background: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/34oq4o0.jpg") center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

.blog-card .photo.photo2 {
 background: url("http://i60.tinypic.com/xeiv79.jpg") center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

.blog-card .details {
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: "Open Sans";
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 height: 300px;
    /*POSITION*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: -100%;
}

.blog-card .details > li {
 padding: 3px 0;
}

.blog-card .details li:before, .blog-card .details .tags ul:before {
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 margin-right: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.blog-card .details .author:before {
 content: "\f007";
}

.blog-card .details .date:before {
 content: "\f133";
}

.blog-card .details .tags ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.blog-card .details .tags ul:before {
 content: "\f02b";
}

.blog-card .details .tags li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 3px;
}

.blog-card .details a {
 color: inherit;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

.blog-card .details a:hover {
 color: #75D13B;
}

.blog-card .description {
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}

.blog-card .description h1 {
 font-family: "Roboto";
 line-height: 1em;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.blog-card .description h2 {
 color: #9b9b9b;
 font-family: "Open Sans";
 line-height: 1.2em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 1.2% 0;
}

.blog-card .description p {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.blog-card .description p:after {
 content: "";
 background: #75D13B;
 height: 6px;
 width: 40px;
        /*POSITION*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 6px;
 left: 0;
}

.blog-card .description a {
 color: #75D13B;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: right;
}

.blog-card .description a:after {
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 content: "\f061";
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 margin-left: -10px;
 opacity: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.blog-card .description a:hover:after {
 margin-left: 5px;
 opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
 .blog-card {
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 900px;
 }

 .blog-card:hover .photo {
  transform: rotate(5deg) scale(1.3);
 }

 .blog-card:hover.alt .photo {
  transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(1.3);
 }

 .blog-card.alt .details {
  padding-left: 30px;
 }

 .blog-card.alt .description {
  float: right;
 }

 .blog-card.alt .description:before {
  transform: skewX(5deg);
  right: -15px;
  left: inherit;
 }

 .blog-card.alt .photo {
  float: right;
 }

 .blog-card .photo {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
 }

 .blog-card .details {
  width: 40%;
 }

 .blog-card .description {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: 0;
 }

 .blog-card .description:before {
  transform: skewX(-5deg);
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
        /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 height:300px;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blog.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blog2.css">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="outer2">
 <div class="container inner">
    <div class="section">
       <div class="col span_2_of_3">
       
<!--LEFT SIDE-->
<div class="blog-card">
 <div class="photo photo1"></div>
 <ul class="details">
  <li class="author"><a href="#">John Doe</a></li>
  <li class="date">Aug. 24, 2015</li>
  <li class="tags">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="description">
  <h1>Learning to Code</h1>
  <h2>Opening a door to the future</h2>
  <p class="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad eum dolorum architecto obcaecati enim dicta praesentium, quam nobis! Neque ad aliquam facilis numquam. Veritatis, sit. Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now. <br> <br> Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now.  Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now.  Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now.  Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now. </p>
  <a href="#">Read More</a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="blog-card alt">
 <div class="photo photo2"></div>
 <ul class="details">
  <li class="author"><a href="#">Jane Doe</a></li>
  <li class="date">July. 15, 2015</li>
  <li class="tags">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="description">
  <h1>Mastering the Language</h1>
  <h2>Java is not the same as JavaScript</h2>
  <p class="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad eum dolorum architecto obcaecati enim dicta praesentium, quam nobis! Neque ad aliquam facilis numquam. Veritatis, sit. Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now. <br> <br> Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now.  Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now.  Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now.  Loren ipsum h Holalala araba aranbd the good dog now. </p>
  <a href="#">Read More</a>
 </div>
</div>

       </div>
    
       <aside class="col span_1_of_3">
          <div class="side-post">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400&text=img" alt="img">
            <p class="side-content">Ut noster tractavissent, summis hic eiusmod te quem. Doctrina velit litteris eu eu fore ingeniis philosophari ne quid o ingeniis ne anim, illum ea iudicem. Pariatur duis dolor hic dolor ad vidisse amet elit ita summis, quo duis te malis.</p>
          </div>
    
          <div class="side-post">
             <p class="side-content">Ultricies lacus et, non orci gravida purus augue integer, sed turpis. Erat dapibus.       Eleifend massa scelerisque, aenean penatibus laoreet ut in.</p>
             <a href="#" class="button">Subscribe!</a>
          </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hm,it becomes evident that below 1200px this solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I did not understand...can you please be more specific

Comment: I added an image. See the spacing on the left and right of the main content. It is bigger on the right.

Comment: on what width you are observing this behaviour?

Comment: I think is is present all the time (excpet when the side-column gets put on the bottom of the page), but it is less evident on wider screens, because our eyes can't detect small deviations

Comment: check this http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/YpYQNN ..is this what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129566/discussion-between-geeky-and-sanjihan).

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS of side post. Your margins are set correctly but the side_post has fixed width. It should be 100%.

old CSS

```
.side-post {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto 1.5em auto;
    width: 15em;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

new CSS

```
.side-post {
    background: #fff;
    /* margin: 0 auto 1.5em auto; */
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about any specific responsive state?